# Is this internalization of a bijection between a set and its powerset possible?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

From [$\sf L-S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) theorems we can have an external bijection $j$ from a set to its powerset. Obviously, $j$ cannot be fully internalized (used in all instances of Replacement). However, partial internalization is possible. The question here is about if $j$ can be partially internalized in the particular manner described below:

$\exists  \alpha: \text{ limit} (\alpha) \land j: V_\alpha \to V_{\alpha +1} \land j \text{ is a bijection }$

$ \forall A  \ \exists B: B=\{\{j(m),j(n)\} \mid \{n,m\} \in A\}$

$ \forall A  \ \exists B: B=\{\{n,m\} \mid  \{j(m),j(n)\} \in A\}$

In the other words, is it consistent to add to the language of $\sf ZF$ a partial function symbol $j$, and add [to axioms of $\sf ZF$] the above three sentences as axioms? Provided, of course, that Replacement doesn't use $j$.

Comment: Interesting question! For what it's worth, even the following version of this question (which I'll phrase model-theoretically for clarity) is unclear to me: suppose $M$ is a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ and $X,Y\in M$ are infinite. Must there be an external bijection $j:X\rightarrow Y$ such that for each $S\in M$ both $$_2\mathsf{Forth}_j(S):=\{\{j(m),j(n)\}:\{m,n\}\in S\}$$ and $$_2\mathsf{Back}_j(S):=\{\{m,n\}:\{j(m),j(n)\}\in S\}$$ are in $M$ as well?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Your version, albeit more general, is very interesting, well to me at least.

Comment: Is the answer known for the version where you just demand that for each set $S$, we have both $j[S]$ and $j^{-1}[S]$ are also sets?

Comment: I don't know, but I guess it"s unknown too. However, if the above hold then it would follow from it.

Comment: Actually I noticed now that the version I asked about is consistent; in fact if $M\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ then one can force it over $M$: Fix infinite sets $X,Y\in M$. Consider the following forcing $\mathbb{P}$, which attempts to build such bijection with this property...

Comment: The conditions are pairs $(f,P,Q,F)$ where $f$ is a finite partial injective function $A\to Y$ where $A\subseteq X$, $P$ is a partition of $X$ into finitely many subsets, each of which is infinite, $Q$ is a partition of $Y$ into finitely many subsets, each of which is infinite, $F:P\to Q$ is a bijection, and $f$ respects $F$, i.e. $f(b)\in F(B)$ for each $b\in A$ and $B\in P$ with $b\in B$. And $(f',P',Q',F')\leq(f,P,Q,F)$ iff $f'$ extends $f$, $P'$ refines $P$, $Q'$ refines $Q$, and $F'$ refines $F$, in that if $B\in P$ and $C\in Q$ and $C\subseteq B$ then $F'(C)\subseteq F(B)$...

Comment: If $G$ is $M$-generic then $j=\bigcup_{p\in G}f^p$ is a bijection $j:X\to Y$ as desired, i.e. $j[S]\in M$ for each $S\in\mathcal{P}(X)\cap M$, and $j^{-1}[S]\in M$ for each $S\in\mathcal{P}(Y)\cap M$. This is a straightforward density calculation. The inifiniteness of the sets $B\in P$ and $C\in Q$, and finiteness of the functions $f$, ensure that $j$ will end up being a bijection...

Comment: And e.g. given $S\in\mathcal{P}(X)\cap M$, and a condition $p=(f,P,Q,F)$, say that $S$ is *$p$-suitable* iff for each $B\in P$, either $B\subseteq S$ or $B\cap S=\emptyset$ or both $B\cap S$ and $B\backslash S$ are infinite. So if $S$ is $p$-suitable then we get a refinement $P_1$ of $P$ given by $P_1=\{B\cap S\bigm|B\in P\}\cup\{B\backslash S\bigm|B\in P\}$, and all elements of $P_1$ are infinite, and note that $S$ is the union of some (finite) subset $D\subseteq P_1$...

Comment: It is now easy to find a condition $p_1\leq p$ with $p_1=(f,P_1,Q_1,F_1)$ for some $Q_1,F_1$. Note that $p_1$ forces that $\dot{j}[S]=\bigcup (F_1``D)$, and in particular forces $\dot{j}[S]\in\check{V}$...

Comment: Finally note that for every $S\in\mathcal{P}(X)\cap M$ and every condition $p$, $S$ is a finite variant of some $p$-suitable $S'$, so by density we will get some such $S'$ with $j[S']\in V$, but then it follows that $j[S]\in V$. It is completely analogous going in reverse, i.e. for $j^{-1}$.

Comment: Remark: Note that in $M[G]$, $j$ induces a bijection $j^+:\mathcal{P}(X)\cap M[G]\to \mathcal{P}(Y)\cap M[G]$ (i.e. $j^+(S)=j[S]$), and we have $j^+[(\mathcal{P}(X))\cap M]=\mathcal{P}(Y)\cap M$, so $j$ induces a bijection $k:\mathcal{P}(X)\cap M\to\mathcal{P}(Y)\cap M$ in this way. So we can ask whether $k$ also has the same property, i.e. whether $k[S]\in M$ and $k^{-1}[S]\in M$ for each $S\in M$. If so, it would give a strengthening of the desired property in the original question. But it's not obvious to me how to extend the forcing argument to do this (or to do the original question).

Comment: I think this needs to be put as an answer to a partial result related to my question or to Noah's version.

Comment: @FarmerS, can we get a partial resut of $j$ obeying the condition you proved and also obeying existence of a *set* $_2\mathsf{Back}_j(S) $ for every set $S$?

Comment: @Zuhairal-Johar I don't see that either.

Comment: @FarmerS, possibly we need to do that in some large cardinal hypothesis, and possibly one that is incompatible with choice?

Comment: @FarmerS, is choice necessary for your proof? I mean would the same work over *any* model $M$ of $\sf ZF$?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar, it would be enough to assume that $M$ models ZF + "$X$ and $Y$ have no amorphous subsets". If both $X$ and $Y$ had amorphous subsets then one would have to match them up in some way I suppose, the plausibility of which it seems might depend on the circumstances.