# Can we have a bijection between a set and its powerset with the following properties?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms

This question is related to a question [Is this internalization of a bijection between a set and its powerset possible?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405567/is-this-internalization-of-a-bijection-between-a-set-and-its-powerset-possible) lately posted to $\cal MO$. Similarly, we add one primitive  unary partial function “$j$” to the language of $\sf ZF$.

The question is about if we can add the following on top of axioms of $\sf ZF$ [$j $ not used in Replacement nor Separation]?

$\exists \alpha: \text{ limit} (\alpha) \land j: V_\alpha \to V_{\alpha +1}  \land  \text{$j$ is a bijection }$

$ \forall S: \text {$j[S]$; $j^{-1} [S]$  both exist }$

$ \exists S: S= \{\{x,y\}\mid \exists z: z \in j(x) \land z \in j(y) \}$

Where: $g[S]=\{g(x) \mid x \in S\}$.

The first two conditions have already been [proved](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405567/is-this-internalization-of-a-bijection-between-a-set-and-its-powerset-possible?#comment1039997_405567) consistent, it's the addition of the last condtion that is unsolved.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the motivation for the third condition. Can you clarify what draws your interest to that condition?

Comment: @SridharRamesh, this is ccnnected to proving Con(NF), but this is another story.